# My If statement is not compare with mysql data?

Tags: php, mysql

Halo, I got a If statement here but is not working.
The system just pass me to the last page which I set it.
And that is not what I want.
What I want here is when the user login, the system automatic check the user belong to which department and send them to the correct page.

```
$departmentsql="SELECT department FROM staff_table";
$departmentsqlresult=mysql_query($departmentsql);
$departmentcount=mysql_num_rows($departmentsqlresult);
if($departmentcount == "A"){
header("location:departmentA.php");
}
else if($departmentcount == "B"){
header("location:departmentB.php");
}
else if ($departmentcount == "C"){
header("location:departmentC.php")
}
```

The system just send me to the departmentC.php every time, no matter which user I login.
And that is not what I want.
Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code?
Appreciate for your answer. Thanks

Comment: mysql_num_rows returns a number of rows in results, not a letter. Check this instead [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php). And finally don`t use mysql_* it's deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` returns a number but you are comparing it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors :

```
if($departmentcount == "A"){
  header("location:departmentA.php");
}
```

**>>** `$departmentcount` will contain a numric value

PHP doesn't implictyly typecast, so when you compare 2 values, it treats both of them of same *type*.

On comparison, since you are comparing `$departmentcount` with a `char`, it'll expect `$departmentcount` to contain char value too, which is not the case...so condition becomes false for all of your `if` and `elseif`, hence no output

Compare it like

```
if($departmentcount == 10) //compare with number
```

**>>** when you'll compare successfully, header wont redirect, because your syntax for `header` is also incorrect

Correct it this way :

```
header("Location: departmentA.php");
  /* you need a ^^ space here */
```

Comment: Sure you *can* compare an int to a string in php

Comment: One last nitpicking remark. The `Location` header expects a full absolute URI :-)

Answer (score 0):

First you do not seem to be taking the logged in user and doing a lookup that way, it seems currently you would return all departments regardless of the user who has logged in.

Next mysql_num_rows returns the number of rows returned in that query you would need mysql_fetch_row, mysql_fetch_object etc

Answer (score 0):

You did mistake use mysql_fetch_array

```
$departmentsql="SELECT department FROM staff_table";
$departmentsqlresult=mysql_query($departmentsql);
$departmentcount=mysql_fetch_array($departmentsqlresult);
if($departmentcount[0] == "A"){
header("location:departmentA.php");
}
else if($departmentcount[0] == "B"){
header("location:departmentB.php");
}
else if ($departmentcount[0] == "C"){
header("location:departmentC.php")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check what's the [basic difference between mysql_num_rows and mysql_fetch_array](http://phpsolver.blogspot.in/2011/11/difference-between-mysqlfetchassoc.html) . As suggested by other it will works fine. 
If still you facing issue then to use "===". [comparing values in php](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/php-questions/difference-between-and-in-php/).